# Who/what are these entities in Tron that don't follow the normal pattern for 'Programs'?

Tags: tron

During the scenes set at the Input/Output tower, we see characters that do not conform to the normal 'Program' human. One is clearly not even a human. The others are humans with bizarre accessories.

### Who or what are these entities?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*...as the elevator platform arrives, and they step off. We get the  sense of massive, over-size ceilings, floors, windows and machinery, dwarfing **the programs who come to the Tower to communicate**, preparing them for the experience, as a vaulting cathedral prepared the sinner for confession. But here, everything is composed of clean, sharp, angular surfaces.  On this second story there is floor and ceiling, but no outer wall, so we can still see the city-grid below and beyond.*

Comment: "Inoperative data pushers" and/or "nested macros", according to the film dialogue. Whatever that means. The hooded ones seem to have acquired the fan name "Data Monks".

Comment: No help from "*The Art of Tron*". They're not mentioned at all

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - "*cryptarithmetic priests*" says the novelisation

Comment: @Valorum I like that better than "data monks". Might be this year's halloween outfit.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 40 year anniversary. Just in time.

Comment: From a programer's perspective, maybe they are paused threads or unused resources (available computing power)

Answer (score 11):

The film's [official novelisation](https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/TRON_(novelization)) goes into a little more detail. In brief, these are various programs.

> When he’d neared the Factory Complex, he halted the light-cycle and
> permitted it to de-rezz. Discarding the useless handlebars, he took in
> his surroundings, grimly, incensed at the cruelty and waste he saw. He
> trotted from the alleyway where he’d stopped, out onto a broad
> thoroughfare. **Programs of all sorts walked there, many of them
> strangely shaped because of their functions.**
>
> There was a Warrior of a type not known to Tron. He had an energy lance cradled in the crook of his left arm; his right arm and part of his helmet had been blown away, leaving only long, trailing steamers of glowing filaments. A **little light-exchange monitor, outmoded and enclosed in his glassy bulb,** passed by. Tron had to step around **a segmented connectoid** that, crawling along like a huge, blind worm, nearly bumped into him. He recognized **cryptarithmetic priests** by their circuited cassocks. But there was little animation to anyone, and no enthusiasm. Tron saw one program speaking to another, and stopped to listen.

Comment: A couple of those people are clearly what could only be described as 'Programs of the Night'